# While Running Junit Test i get Error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.log4j.Priority

Tags: log4j, ejb-3.0, log4j2, openjpa

[Click here to see the logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PSwl.png)

I am using following jars in my Junit test

log4j-api-2.3.jar
log4j-core-2.3.jar
junit-4.10.jar
ojdbc6.jar
openjpa-all-2.1.1.jar

I see that class org.apache.log4j.Priority doesn't exist in Log4j 2.3 version?
Then I changed the  value for the property openjpa.Log from **log4j** to "**DefaultLevel=WARN, Runtime=INFO, Tool=INFO, SQL=TRACE**" in persistence.xml and I don't see the error anymore.
Could someone tell the cause for the Error and also how changing the value for property openjpa.log solved the issue?

Answer (score 0):

org.apache.log4j.Priority is a class in Log4j 1.x. If you included log4j-1.2-api-2.3.jar the error should disappear.

When you set openjpa.log you are configuring OpenJPA to use Log4j 1.x for logging. When you changed the configuration OpenJPA determined it should use its basic logging implementation instead.

http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.3/apache-openjpa/docs/ref_guide_logging.html discusses this.